# Closed form of a sum $ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{((i-1)x)^2+y^2}$

Tags: summation

Consider a sum:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{((i-1)x)^2+y^2}$$

with $x$ and $y$ being (non-zero) constants. Is it possible to obtain a nice closed form of this expression?

Comment: Why exactly there is no closed form for this?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect to that?

Comment: I'm new to this topic. I'm just curious, how is it possible to determine there is no general closed form?

Comment: But indeed, $x<<y$. How does one proceed to estimate such sum?

Comment: Approximating them by Riemann sums of the function $$f(t)=\frac1{t^2+1}$$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(((k-1)x)%5E2+%2B+y%5E2),+k%3D1+to+n

Answer (score 4):

If we consider the method explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969378/what-is-the-value-of-the-series-sum-n-geq-1-frac1n21/1969629#1969629) to prove
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+1} = \frac{\pi\coth \pi-1}{2} $$
we may easily tweak it to prove also that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(nx)^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{y^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{1+n^2\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2y^2}+\frac{\pi \coth\left(\frac{\pi  y}{x}\right)}{2 x y}}.$$
So, even if the partial sums do not have a nice closed form, the whole series does.

Comment: your answer is much appreciable (as usual!). However I do not understand your conclusion on the partial sums: from your answer we should be able to give a nice close form also to them (see my post below), or did I overlook some point?

Comment: @GCab: you already completed my answer (and (+1) for that, of course). My idea was exactly to write $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{(nx)^2+y^2}$ as the whole series (for which we know the closed form) minus the contribute $$\sum_{n>N}\frac{1}{(nx)^2+y^2}$$ that is simple to approximate with an integral, as already suggested by Did in the comments.

Comment: and what about using the digamma  function ?

Comment: @GCab: the $\coth$ above comes from the digamma reflection formula, if you like.

Comment: good, so the circle closes.  However I cannot immediately see how the reflection formula can be applied here (and passing from $cot$ to $coth$)

Answer (score 2):

*------ Complementing Jack's answer  -----*

Actually, since we have the formula for the infinite summation
$$
S\left( {x,y} \right) = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} }}}  = \frac{1}
{{2y^{\,2} }} + \frac{{\pi \coth \left( {\pi y/x} \right)}}
{{2xy}}
$$
then, for a partial one we will have
$$
\begin{gathered}
  S\left( {x,y,n} \right) = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - 1} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} }}}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} }}}  - \sum\limits_{n\, \leqslant \,k} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} }}}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} }}}  - \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {\left( {x + n} \right) + k} \right)^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} }}}  =  \hfill \\
   = S\left( {x,y} \right) - S\left( {x + n,y} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

*------ in another way  -----*

$$
\begin{gathered}
  S\left( {x,y,n} \right) = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - 1} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2}  + y^{\,2} }}}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - 1} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x + k} \right)^{\,2}  - \left( {iy} \right)^{\,2} }}}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - 1} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x + iy + k} \right)\left( {x - iy + k} \right)}}}  = \frac{1}
{{2iy}}\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - 1} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x - iy + k} \right)}}}  - \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\;\frac{1}
{{\left( {x + iy + k} \right)}}} } \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{2iy}}\left( {\psi ^{\left( 0 \right)} \left( {x - iy + n} \right) - \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)} \left( {x + iy + n} \right) + \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)} \left( {x + iy} \right) - \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)} \left( {x - iy} \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{y}\left( {\operatorname{Im} \left( {\psi ^{\left( 0 \right)} \left( {x + iy} \right)} \right) - \operatorname{Im} \left( {\psi ^{\left( 0 \right)} \left( {x + iy + n} \right)} \right)} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \bracks{\pars{k - 1}x}^{2} + y^{2}} & =
{1 \over xy}\,\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k - \pars{y/x}\ic} =
{1 \over xy}\,\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{1 \over k - \pars{y/x}\ic} - {1 \over k + n - \pars{y/x}\ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{-\,{\Im\pars{H_{n - 1 - y\ic/x} - H_{-1 - y\ic/x}} \over xy}}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{H_{z}}$ is an [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Answer (score 0):

As already wrote, there is no nice closed form. A way to see an approximation is the following. Using [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we have $$S_{N}\left(z\right)=\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}z^{2}}=\frac{N}{1+N^{2}z^{2}}+2z^{2}\int_{1}^{N}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor t}{\left(1+t^{2}z^{2}\right)^{2}}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function and since $t-1<\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor \leq t
 $ we get $$S_{N}\left(z\right)<\frac{N}{1+N^{2}z^{2}}+2z^{2}\left(\int_{1}^{N}\frac{1}{1+t^{2}z^{2}}-\frac{1}{\left(1+z^{2}t^{2}\right)^{2}}dt\right)
 $$ $$=\frac{\arctan\left(Nz\right)}{z}-\frac{\arctan\left(z\right)}{z}+\frac{1}{z^{2}+1}
 $$ and in the same way we get $$S_{N}\left(z\right)>\frac{N}{1+N^{2}z^{2}}+2z^{2}\int_{1}^{N}\frac{t^{2}-t}{\left(1+t^{2}z^{2}\right)^{2}}dt
 $$ $$=\frac{\arctan\left(Nz\right)}{z}-\frac{\arctan\left(z\right)}{z}+\frac{1}{1+N^{2}z^{2}}
 $$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{y^{2}+n^{2}x^{2}}=\frac{1}{y^{2}}+\frac{1}{y^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{2}}
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{y^{2}}+\frac{S_{N-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{y^{2}}.$$
For the complete series [another interesting method](http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf) is the following $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f\left(n\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{residues of }\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)f\left(z\right)\textrm{ at }f\left(z\right)\textrm{'s poles}\right\} 
 $$ and observing that $$\frac{1}{y^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{2}}=\frac{1}{2y^{2}}+\frac{1}{2y^{2}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{2}}
 $$ and since we have poles at $\pm\frac{iy}{x}
 $ we get $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{2}}=\frac{y\pi\coth\left(\pi y/x\right)}{x}
 $$ and so $$\frac{1}{y^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{2}}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2y^{2}}+\frac{\pi\coth\left(\pi y/x\right)}{2yx}}.$$