# What is the value of the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

What is the value of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{1+n^2}$$
I don't know how to solve it.
I tried to solve it by power series, but I failed.

Comment: I'm afraid it's one of those "inspection" answers, where you have to draw upon your knowledge of familiar and well known series formulas -- probably a disappointing solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{\pi x}{2}\coth \pi x=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\left ( \frac{n}{x} \right )^2+1}$$
at $x=1$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}\coth \pi -\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 6):

I will give an elementary solution based on the following lemmas:

> **Lemma 1.** For any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$,
>   $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{1}{1+n^2}.$$
>   **Proof:** integration by parts.
>
> **Lemma 2.** The following series is the Fourier series of a $2\pi$-periodic sawtooth wave $f(x)$,
>  that over the interval $(0,2\pi)$ equals $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$:
>   $$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin nx}{n} $$
>   **Proof:** direct computation of Fourier coefficients.

By Lemma **1** and Lemma **2**,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+1}&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-x}\,dx\\(\text{periodicity of } f(x))\qquad&=&\left(1+\frac{1}{e^{2\pi}}+\frac{1}{e^{4\pi}}+\ldots\right)\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-x}\,dx\\[0.2cm]&=&\frac{e^{2\pi}}{e^{2\pi}-1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\pi-x}{2}e^{-x}\,dx\\[0.2cm](\text{direct computation})\qquad &=&\color{red}{\frac{\pi\coth\pi-1}{2}}.\end{eqnarray*} $$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** It's [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Cotangent) that
$$\pi\cot(\pi z)=\frac{1}{z}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z}{z^2-n^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2} + 1} & =
{1 \over 2\ic}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n + 1 - \ic} -
{1 \over n + 1 + \ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2\ic}\bracks{\vphantom{\Large A}\Psi\pars{1 + \ic} - \Psi\pars{1 - \ic}}\qquad
\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2\ic}\braces{\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
{1 \over \ic} - \bracks{\vphantom{\Large A}\Psi\pars{1 - \ic} - \Psi\pars{\ic}}}\qquad
\pars{~\Psi\ Recurrence~}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2\ic}\,
\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}\pi\cot\pars{\pi\ic}}\qquad
\pars{~Euler\ Reflection\ Formula~}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 2} - {\pi \over 2\ic}\,\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}-\ic\coth\pars{\pi}} =
\bbx{\ds{\pi\coth\pars{\pi} - 1 \over 2}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it :)

Comment: @ArturodonJuan Thanks. It's a straightforward method and it's widely used ( and explained ) in the old *Abramowitz and Stegun Table*.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm a physics student who learned it from Arfken's book (and they cite Abramowitz and Stegun)

Answer (score 1):

It is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179) that
$$
\mathrm{PV}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n+z}=\pi\cot(\pi z)\tag{1}
$$
converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2+z^2}
&=\frac i{2z}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n+iz}+\frac1{-n+iz}\right)\\
&=\frac i{2z}\left[\mathrm{PV}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n+iz}-\frac1{iz}\right]\\
&=-\frac1{2z^2}+\frac{\pi i}{2z}\cot(\pi iz)\\[6pt]
&=-\frac1{2z^2}+\frac\pi{2z}\coth(\pi z)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Plugging in $z=1$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2+1}=-\frac12+\frac\pi2\coth(\pi)\tag{3}
$$